# Power Distribution Blocks for DC voltage?

Tags: wiring, protection, power-engineering

So, I'm pretending to use a somewhat uncommon component for my generator system. With an alternator, I will generate 24 V DC and a maximum of 100 A. My question is, can I use a power distribution block like one of [these](https://w5.siemens.com/italy/web/bassatensione/prodottidibassatensione/apparecchimodulari/interruttorimagnetotermici/accessori/Documents/SIEMENS%20-%20Blocchi%20di%20distribuzione%205ST250%20%20(ENG).pdf)?

My initial guess would be that yes, I can use it, but as these products are not specified for what I intend to do I'm asking if my project will bump into any strange electrical problems.

Comment: I guess you could use that distr. block, the Amps. rating is > 100 A so that's OK. However I think the one you linked to is **overkill** and far to expensive for your needs. I would use something like: https://www.ebay.com.au/p/10-Way-1to-Marine-Boat-150a-Power-Distribution-Bus-Bar-Terminal-Block-12v-24v/2295684974  instead. There are more, just Google for "24V distribution block".

Comment: *"as these products are not specified for what I intend to do"* -- what is it that you intend to do, aside from splitting the power connection?